# The difference when declare an new object

Tags: oop

This is the code snippet

```
public class Square{
   private double length;
   private double width;

   public Square(double a, double b){
         length = a;
         width = b;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
      Square box = new box(3.0,5.0);
   }
}
```

Here is my question, what is the difference between `Square box = new box(3.0,5.0);` and `Square box = new Square(3.0,5.0);`

the new box(3.0,5.0) suppose is to be call the box constructor which I don't have. but it will call Square constructor as well. It really confuse me why written in this way also is correct

Comment: where did you even get "box"? is that a child class of Square?

Comment: no, but my lecturer said this is also correct although I dont have box  as my child class for Square

Comment: So its either you misunderstood your lecturer or your lecturer was incorrect, I'm guessing most likely the first situation is what you are having right now

Comment: I understand that if I don't have box class which I cant instantiate the box constructor, but my lecturer did not argue that this is a wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is `new Square(3.0, 5.0)` is valid but `new box(3.0, 5.0)` is a compile error. If it's actually compiling for you then your project must also include another class called `box` (perhaps in another file) which you haven't included in your post.

Comment: If you had a class called "box" which had a constructor that took two floats as parameters, it would theoretically be correct. Otherwise, no.

Comment: I agree with your statement here, just don't know why my lecturer said nothing wrong >.<

Comment: @Jiazzyuser I don't know the big picture of what your lecturer was talking about, but I can say with certainty that *given the code you posted*, any reference to some type called `box` would be an error. It would only work if there really were a type called `box` declared somewhere (and in that case it would not call the `Square` constructor unless the `box` class derived from `Square`, or contained a `Square` object).

Comment: @dvnrrs my lecturer said that I write `Square box = new box(3.0,5.0);` is also correct to write it this way even though there is no box class existed

Comment: @Jiazzyuser Not true, at least in Java which is what this code appears to be (if it's not Java [or C#] then it might be a different story, but I'm not familiar with any language where this would be the case).